# Using independent ngModel in Angular 2+ Reactive Form

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular2-ngmodel

I've got a reactive form on my page.

Here's a summary of the code:

```
<div class="container">
<form [formGroup]="transactionForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(transactionForm)">
     <div formGroupName="userInfoGroup" class="form-group">
          <input formControlName="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Larry" id="name"> 
     </div>
     ...
</form>   
</div>
```

Here's where it gets tricky. I want the user to be able to input the information of the person who referred them (who may or may not exist in our database). So I want to use [ng-bootstrap typeahead](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples) to provide a way to **search** for an existing user.

So I copied the `html` and `ts` code from ng-bootstrap, and now my template looks like

```
<div class="container">
<form [formGroup]="transactionForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(transactionForm)">
     <div formGroupName="userInfoGroup" class="form-group">
          <input formControlName="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Larry" id="name"> 
     </div>
     <input id="typeahead-http" type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="model" [ngbTypeahead]="searchForReferrer" placeholder="Search for Referrer" />
     ...
</form>   
</div>
```

When I run this now I get errors:

```
RegisterTransaction.html:154 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'lift' of undefined
    at tapOperatorFunction (tap.js:52)
    at _do (do.js:48)
    at NgbTypeahead.webpackJsonp.../../../../@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/typeahead/typeahead.js.NgbTypeahead.ngOnInit (typeahead.js:73)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.es5.js:10843)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.es5.js:12341)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.es5.js:12284)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.es5.js:13141)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.es5.js:13082)
    at Object.View_RegisterTransaction_0._co [as updateDirectives] (RegisterTransaction.html:163)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.es5.js:13067)
  [1]: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples
```

and if I just remove `[ngbTypeahead]="searchForReferrer"`  I get

```
RegisterTransaction.html:154 ERROR Error: 
      ngModel cannot be used to register form controls with a parent formGroup directive.  Try using
      formGroup's partner directive "formControlName" instead.  Example:


    <div [formGroup]="myGroup">
      <input formControlName="firstName">
    </div>

    In your class:

    this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
       firstName: new FormControl()
    });

      Or, if you'd like to avoid registering this form control, indicate that it's standalone in ngModelOptions:

      Example:


    <div [formGroup]="myGroup">
       <input formControlName="firstName">
       <input [(ngModel)]="showMoreControls" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
    </div>


    at Function.webpackJsonp.../../../forms/@angular/forms.es5.js.TemplateDrivenErrors.modelParentException (forms.es5.js:4110)
    at NgModel.webpackJsonp.../../../forms/@angular/forms.es5.js.NgModel._checkParentType (forms.es5.js:4430)
    at NgModel.webpackJsonp.../../../forms/@angular/forms.es5.js.NgModel._checkForErrors (forms.es5.js:4417)
    at NgModel.webpackJsonp.../../../forms/@angular/forms.es5.js.NgModel.ngOnChanges (forms.es5.js:4324)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.es5.js:10840)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.es5.js:12341)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.es5.js:12284)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.es5.js:13141)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.es5.js:13082)
    at Object.View_RegisterTransaction_0._co [as updateDirectives] (RegisterTransaction.html:163)
```

**How do I properly use this search ahead inside an existing reactive form?**

Comment: So, please show the code for `searchForReferrer`

Comment: @AluanHaddad it's exactly the same from the example on ng-bootstrap (the Wikipedia example)

Comment: I'm pretty sure Wikipedia doesn't have such an article. Anyway you are not returning something or not setting a required binding somewhere.

Comment: @AluanHaddad ng-bootstrap has an example of a typeahead that queries wikipedia https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples

Comment: Right, so your function `searchForReferrer` returns an observable? You said your code was exactly the same but it is at least different in name. Why not post it?

Comment: @AluanHaddad see answer I just posted

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @Aluan Haddad, who prodded me to ensure my code was **exactly** the same as the sample code, I eventually realized it was indeed **not** the same. I had inadvertently added curly braces around the `return` portion of the arrow function.

So instead of

```
search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
    text$
      .debounceTime(300)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .do(() => this.searching = true)
      .switchMap(term =>
        this._service.search(term)
          .do(() => this.searchFailed = false)
          .catch(() => {
            this.searchFailed = true;
            return Observable.of([]);
          }))
      .do(() => this.searching = false)
      .merge(this.hideSearchingWhenUnsubscribed);
```

I had

```
search = (text$: Observable<string>) => {
    text$
      .debounceTime(300)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .do(() => this.searching = true)
      .switchMap(term =>
        this._service.search(term)
          .do(() => this.searchFailed = false)
          .catch(() => {
            this.searchFailed = true;
            return Observable.of([]);
          }))
      .do(() => this.searching = false)
      .merge(this.hideSearchingWhenUnsubscribed);
}
```

Comment: That is what I figured, glad you discovered the underlying issue. +1

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. +1 to you too. Such a tricky problem since error message is so vague

Comment: Yeah, I know that `lift` is a method on `Observable` so I had an inkling but yeah it is awkward to debug because these methods are consumed directly from markup and don't get typechecked. If the typeahead API was called via TypeScript, it would been like `[ts] Error: cannot assign void to Obersvable<T>.` It might be helpful to write unit tests for these sorts of methods since they are bound only in markup.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is given in the error message only. You can not use ngModel inside form-group. If you want to use ngModel then you need to specify that element's standalone: true by passing  [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" in that element. You just need to write that element as:

```
<input id="typeahead-http" type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="model" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [ngbTypeahead]="searchForReferrer" placeholder="Search for Referrer" />
```

This should resolve your issue.